# csh/tcsh Tab Completion with "complete = enhance" Strange Behavior

Tags: shell, command-line, autocomplete, tcsh, csh

`set complete = enhance` is put in .cshrc, and we have two files, `test_ab_dd.c` and `test_abc_dd.c`.

If I type `test_ab_<TAB>` in the command line, csh DOES NOT autocomplete to `test_ab_dd.c`. It suggests both `test_ab_dd.c` and `test_abc_dd.c`. I have to type all the way to the end. Shouldn't this no longer be ambiguous? It completes just fine in bash.

This only happens with `complete` set to `enhance`. I wanted it that way since it allows case-insensitivity.

Is there any way to keep case-insensitivity while resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `complete` to `enhance` it considers periods, hyphens and *underscores* as word separators and not as the characters like you expected.

So basically the answer is no since this is a "feature" of setting  `complete` to `enhance`.